# Two positive charges $q$ and $3q$ and are a length 10 cm apart

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

(a) Where could a third charge be placed so as to
experience no net force?

The solution is as follows

$$ K_e \frac{q_1q_3}{x^2}=K_e\frac{3q_1q_3}{(x-a)^2}$$
I understand you can cancel out the charges and solve for a.

What I don't understand is why it wouldn't be this
$$ K_e \frac{q_1q_3}{x^2} +K_e\frac{3q_1q_3}{(x-a)^2}=0$$

Because when you sum forces shouldn't it be zero? That is what the question is asking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two forces experienced by the third charge will either both be attractive, or both be repulsive. And therefore their directions are always opposite,so to cancel out their magnitude must be the same. That is how the solution goes.

Your solution would be correct, except when summing the forces to be zero you have to consider that one of them has a negative sign (because they are in opposite directions), and then if you just rearrange you obtain the first equality.

Comment: That answers my question and if I were to add the negative to the other side then that would align with the solution thank you.